# Windows 10 1809 - Clock Speed Stuck at 0.40 Ghz

Tags: windows-10, clockspeed

lately my laptop clockspeed is stuck at 0.40 ghz that turned me lagging so bad , i dont know why but it only happen sometimes , like when im booting up my pc it 3ghz-2ghz until about 10 minutes and it turned to be 0.40 ghz again, heres all the picture of my pc specification, All i have tried is , setting the power option , my bios is up to date

[DXDIAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uUm5.png)

Comment: How do you know it's really at 400Mhz, is the reporting tool accurate? How's the heat sink & fans & airflow & temperature? Is the cpu overheating & slowing down? Battery good, does it happen only when plugged in or unplugged?

Comment: @Xen2050 im checking from task manager and cpu-z the fan speed is normal ,temp between 49-50 celcius but not higher than that , i got this problem when plugged , never unplugged because im never leave house right now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processor speed limited at 0.4 GHz](https://superuser.com/questions/1420298/processor-speed-limited-at-0-4-ghz)

Comment: @phuclv have seen it, none of it have same on mine